# .exe file created by C programming through gcc compiler isn't executing

Tags: 12.04, gcc, c

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop and Ubuntu 11.04 on laptop. I am writing c program which contains math. I am creating executable file through the command:

```
gcc -o filename.exe filename.c -lm (compilation)
```

This will create a filename.exe file. I can now execute it through terminal command:

```
./filename.exe (execution)
```

I have laptop. It has Ubuntu 11.04. I store files in NTFS partition. These sequence of commands works well in my laptop. But if same file I copy in my desktop's NTFS partition, which is Ubuntu 12.04 and then runs then it doesn't work. It compiles but doesn't executes. I am getting the answer:

```
bash: ./filename.exe: Permission denied
```

I searched in internet. They suggested that you can change the permission of file by below command:

```
chmod u+x filename.exe
```

But I got same answer: `Permission denied`. I tried manually through GUI through property --> permission --> checking "allow executing file as program" and that is not working. It uncheckes automatically. I searched in the internet and I got answer that it is not advisable to change permission for every file each and every time of execution. better you can change permission of entire NTFS partition by following command:

```
chmod -R 777 /media/partition (where partition is NTFS type.)
```

This is supposed to change the partition permission to rw and executable mode. But this is also not solving my problem.

Comment: Doesn't really have to do with the question per se, nor may fix your issue, but may I suggest that you download and use the clang frontend from the llvm compiler infrastructure? It supports way better diagnostics than gcc does. If you want to give it a try: sudo apt-get install clang. Other than that it operates in the same way as gcc.

Answer (score 2):

As other already mentioned, the problem is caused by using NTFS, which does not support Unix-style permissions.

A workaround would be to mount the partition so ALL the files on it have `execute` bit set. This might fix your immediate problem but may break again when compiling more complex programs. It may also be a security risk.

A proper solutions would be not to use an NTFS partition to compile programs :)

Answer (score 1):

There are likely some settings in how you mount the NTFS partition that denies you the right to execute files on it.  You should be able to fix this by editing the options in your /etc/fstab.  See this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1378519 .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using ntfs which does not have the execute permission. One thing you might do is to add 'exec' to the the end of the parameters in the entry for this drive in your /etc/fstab file

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1570369
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=126406

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I followed the following website.

- http://www.sinarpelangi.com/how-to-set-executable-permission-at-ntfs-partition-on-linux/

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null (It will list all the partitions we have. In my computer, it displays,)
sudo umount /media/partitionname
sudo mkdir /media/partitionname
sudo mount /dev/sdaX -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002 /media/partitionname
```

where partitionname is the name of your NTFS partition and in sdaX, X is number obtained from the first command i.e. `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`.

Now I can write C program, can execute in the same partition (in NTFS). Without these commands, the file color was white when the command `ls -al` is used. But now the color has changed to green after listing it through `ls -al` command.